# How to use button to control Canvas in Java?

Tags: java, awt

I am asked to use the code in the texts book for an assignment.
How can I trans the data from Frame into Canvas?
For example,

```java
public class test extends Frame {
   public static void main(String[] args) {new DefPoly();}
   int position = -1;
   test() {
      xxxxx
      });

      setSize(500, 300);
      Button button1 = new Button("lower end points");
      Button button2 = new Button("upper end points");

      button1.setBounds(20, 30,100,20);
      button2.setBounds(20, 60,100,20);
      
      add(button1);
      add(button2);
   
      add("Center", new Cvtest());
      setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
      setVisible(true);
   }
}

class CvTest extends Canvas {
   CvTest(){
      xxxxxxx
   }
   int position=1;
   int x1, y1, x2, y2;
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.drawLine(position*x1, y1, x2, y2);
   }
}
```

The code is just for an example, I want to control the direction of the Line by using `position`. Therefore I add `actionListener` in the Frame, but failed to change the value of `position`. Do I need to see more about MCV?

Answer (score 0):

add a method: public setPosition(int position)  in class CvTest
and then invoke this method in  actionListener to change position
all code like this:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test extends Frame {
    int position = -1;
    CvTest cvTest;
    
    public Test(){
        setSize(500, 300);
        cvTest = new CvTest();
        
        Button button1 = new Button("lower end points");
        Button button2 = new Button("upper end points");

        button1.setBounds(20, 30,100,20);
        button2.setBounds(20, 60,100,20);
        
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // here can change position
                cvTest.setPosition(position);
            }
            
        });
        
        add(button1);
        add(button2);
     
        
        add("Center", cvTest);
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
   public static void main(String[] args) {
         new Test();
   }
}

class CvTest extends Canvas {
   int position=1;
   int x1, y1, x2, y2;
   
   CvTest(){

   }
   
   public void setPosition(int position){
       this.position = position;
   }
   
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.drawLine(position*x1, y1, x2, y2);
   }
}
```